# OD660 readings of yeast

Tags: spectrophotometry, optical-properties

I am working on a yeast fermentation project, and I am getting final OD660 reading of 1.85 for different media: yeast extracts+cane molasses, nitrogen source+cane molasses, and glucose+cane molasses at different concentrations. The final OD reading is the same for all media. Is it normal? Are my readings correct?

Comment: I cannot comment on the expected growth rates in different media, but in order to avoid errors in measurement, I would dilute my samples to achieve optical densities in the 0.1 to 1.0 range.

Answer (score 2):

Many inexpensive spectrophotometers cannot measure absorbances over 1.5 or so reliably. It's possible that you're out of the measurement range of your instrument. Try diluting your samples with water first. If you dilute 1:1, then the absorbance value of your sample is double what you measure (assuming the Beer-Lambert law is valid in this situation)

Also, I imagine molasses is very absorbent at that wavelength so it might be obscuring any change from the yeast and it may not be possible to measure the yeast growth by absorbance, with such a matrix.